# which one is best way to implements OnClickListener in Android?

Tags: android

which one is best way to implements OnClickListener Interface in Android.

/*- First - */

```
public class EmployeeActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button btnUpdate = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnUpdate);
        Button btnEdit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnEdit);

        btnUpdate.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnEdit.setOnClickListener(this);

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (v == btnAddEmployee) 
      {}
    if (v == btnUpdate) 
    {}
}
```

/*- Second -*/

```
public class EmployeeActivity extends Activity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button btnUpdate = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnUpdate);
        Button btnEdit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnEdit);

        btnUpdate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

        btnEdit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't ask what's better - that's a subjective question. I don't think this can be converted to a "list of cons and pros" question, either.

Answer (score 2):

> which one is best way to implements OnClickListener Interface in Android

This depends solely on what fits best for you as the developer. They all work the same and you even have another option to declare `onClick` in xml. I like the first especially if you will have multiple `Button`s that you want to share functionality. But a better way to do the first is to `switch` on the `id` of the `View` being clicked. Something like

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int id = v.getId();
    switch (id)
    {
        case R.id.btnUpdate:
           // do work
           break;
        case R.id.btnEdit
           // do work for edit button
           break;
    }
    // put shared functionality code like starting an Activity, calling a method, etc...
}
```

The second I like to use if there is only one or two `Button`s and they have completely different functionality. I think this way makes the code look more cluttered and messy if you have too many `Button`s. But these all work the same and won't change the performance of your app.

Comment: Using switch is probably the cleanest way and easier to distinguish than an endless row of if/else if/... statements.

Answer (score 0):

Neither one is "better." Which one you use is a personal choice, and will depend on which one fits your coding style.

The advantage to the second method is that you can have a unique `OnClickListener` for each View. The advantage to the first option is that all of your `onClick()` code is in one place.

Answer (score 0):

The first method is good.
But rather than if-else. use switch case.

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button btnUpdate = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnUpdate);
        Button btnEdit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnEdit);

        btnUpdate.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnEdit.setOnClickListener(this);

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

       switch(v.getId())
      {
      case R.id.btnUpdate:
        //your work
       break
}
```

Comment: I prefer your approach ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your first example is incorrect, you shouldn't compare the objects like that.  You need to do something like:

```
switch(v.getId()) {
    case R.id.yourButton:
        ...
}
```

They are both equivalent for the most part, except the second allocates a new object for each listener.  If I have lots of buttons on one screen I like to organize it like you have in the first example to avoid more boilerplate code.

Comment: Actually...since android tools 14,  using if statements are strongly advised : See [Library Project Revamp](http://tools.android.com/recent/buildchangesinrevision14)

Comment: Of course you can store a button as a member (or final variable) and compare onClick's view argument with it using the equality operator "==". They will both reference the exact same instance. We're not dealing with the "string comparison" problem in Java here. Android's touch input dispatcher does not create copies of button objects or any other clickable view.

Comment: @petey That is for using library projects.  Also, I think you misread what it is saying.  You can't use it as the argument for a switch statement because for library projects they won't be `final` and could change.  Doing it how I have it is perfectly fine because `getId()` is constant.

Comment: Ahh yes. you are right.

Comment: @NobuGames I would be very weary of doing so, and it's definitely not best practice.  It's better to just compare against a known value like an ID.  Any link to what you are saying in your last statement?  I'm curious now to read up on it.

Comment: @trevor-e You can find this "style" of comparing a stored view object with the onClick view argument in the original Android source code (look at CharacterPickerDialog.java for example). If the input dispatcher would really create copies of views it would also have to recreate view hierarchies by making deep copies in order to be consistent. And that's just a waste of memory and CPU cycles. Also just read the documentation of onClick's v argument: "The view that was clicked.". It does not say a copy of the view that was clicked.

Answer (score 0):

It depends upon the number of elements that you have in your current activity. I prefer the second method for few buttons (2 or 3). Any thing more than that I use first method and ofcourse with a switch statement.