# All three buttons lead to same activity?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm having an issue that I can't quite figure out. I've got all three of my buttons to take me to another activity, but the problem is that they all lead me to the activity that I only want my first (Easy) button to do.

**fragment_main_menu.xml:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.app.whosesloganisthat.MainMenu$PlaceholderFragment" >



         <requestFocus />


     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/textView2"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView1"
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         android:text="@string/welcometowhosesloganisthat"
         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/buttonHard"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/buttonHard"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
         android:layout_marginBottom="46dp"
         android:onClick="sendMessage"
         android:text="@string/hard" />

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/buttonEasy"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
         android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
         android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
         android:onClick="sendMessage"
         android:text="@string/easy" />

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/buttonIntermediate"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/buttonEasy"
         android:layout_centerVertical="true"
         android:onClick="sendMessage"
         android:text="@string/intermediate" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainMenu.java:**

```
package com.app.whosesloganisthat;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.os.Build;

public class MainMenu extends ActionBarActivity {
    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.app.whosesloganisthat.MESSAGE";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main_menu); //xml file name which contains button


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
    public void sendMessage(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, EasyLevelInfo.class);


        startActivity(intent);
        // Do something in response to button
    }
    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_menu,
                    container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }
```

**EasyLevelInfo.java:**

```
package com.app.whosesloganisthat;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.os.Build;

public class EasyLevelInfo extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainMenu.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
        // Create the text view
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setTextSize(40);
        textView.setText(message);

        // Set the text view as the activity layout



    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.easy_level_info, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_easy_level_info,
                    container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }
```

**fragment_easy_level_info.xml:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.app.whosesloganisthat.EasyLevelInfo$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
        android:text="@string/youhaveselectedeasy"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks everyone!

Comment: They all use the same class in the same `Intent`...why would you expect them to lead to different activities??? Also, why is this tagged with "forclose"? If it force closes then there will be errors int he logcat which you should post.

Comment: how would I go about doing that then? am i supposed to add another intent? (and sorry about that...i accidentally added forceclose as a tag)

Comment: [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19592740/which-one-is-best-way-to-implements-onclicklistener-in-android/19592786#19592786) change the class in the `Intent()` depending on the button clicked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look in your fragment_main_menu.xml

```
layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView1"
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
     android:text="@string/welcometowhosesloganisthat"
     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

 <Button
     android:id="@+id/buttonHard"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/buttonHard"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     android:layout_marginBottom="46dp"
     android:onClick="sendMessage"
     android:text="@string/hard" />

 <Button
     android:id="@+id/buttonEasy"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
     android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
     android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
     android:onClick="sendMessage"
     android:text="@string/easy" />

 <Button
     android:id="@+id/buttonIntermediate"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/buttonEasy"
     android:layout_centerVertical="true"
     android:onClick="sendMessage"
     android:text="@string/intermediate" />
```

You have three buttons buttonHard, buttonEasy , buttonIntermediate . And these three buttons have attribute `android:onClick = "sendMessage"` This means if one of these buttons is clicked do sendMessage method . Lets look on that method.

```
 public void sendMessage(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, EasyLevelInfo.class);


        startActivity(intent);
        // Do something in response to button
    }
```

This method starts Activity EasyLevelInfo . So if one of three buttons is clicked it will call this sendMessage method and open EasyLevelInfo Activity .